# Jquery , selecting icefaces elements by ID

Tags: jquery, icefaces

With jQuery, we do it like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#orderedlist").append("Please rate: ");
 });
```

and de string appended to component with id orderedlist.

Using icefaces framework , i got a component with id form1:p
i tried accessing it using followin code :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery("#form1:p").append("Please rate: ");
```

the string is appended to the form1 and not to the specified component with id form1:p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the : with two backslashes

```
jQuery("#form1\\:p").append("Please rate: ");
```

See the note at the top of the [selectors api page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 5):

you need to escape it!

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (#;&,.+*~':"!^$=>|/ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the problem is that `:` is a meta character in css selectors, used for `:first` and alike. Try it without the colon, i'm just guessing really, not sure if you could escape it, probably.

Comment: You can escape with two back slashes: "my\\:id"